# text in adorner dissappears when background not transparent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, background, adorner

I have some gridrows with some data on it. if the text is too large, an adorner will show up with the text in it and will act as a ToolTip (long story why i don't use a tooltip anymore, but most of you will know why..). the adorner is a grid with a border and textblock.

Problem is, the background of the row can change (example to Red).
When that happens and I hover over a large text, then the adorner will show up but there is no text shown. according to the code (Debug Mode), the text is loaded in the textblock.

for some reason, the text is not rendered when the background is not normal (meaning of: its not transparent).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**EDIT:** after some testing, it appears it has to do with the BorderBackground thats lies in the Adorner.

Comment: How about calling InvalidateVisual method?

Comment: If you found the solution it is a better practice to write an answer an mark it as accepted ;)